# Is it possible to upload the Image from Local desktop/Laptop to Facebook via WSO2 Facebook ESB connectors

Tags: facebook-graph-api, wso2-esb

I have been trying to upload the image which is in my local system to facebook using WSO2 ESB Facebook connectors.

Below are the things which I tried :

1. With the direct facebook API (provided by Facebook) I tried to upload the image in both ways:

   ```
            a. Using Multipart/form-data to upload an image that is in local desktop 
            b. Tried to upload the image which is already there in google image.
   ```

With both these ways, I am able to upload the image.

2. Now, I am trying to upload the same using WSO2 ESB/EI Facebook connector via ESB sequence. With the ESB connector, I was only able to upload the image which is on the internet already using URL. I was not able to upload the image from local desktop using multipart/from-data.

WSO2 ESB version - 6.3.0
In axis2.xml file multipart form data is enabled in both the message formatters and message builders.

The attached image is the reference for the payload which I am passing for the Facebook connector in the ESB and also the error response which I am facing.

[Payload_and_Error_Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuWiS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Following is a sample request that was obtained from the Facebook official documentation with respect to the photo upload. Here please note that it states that "**To upload a photo, make a request to /object-id/photos where the /object-id can be a user, page, event or album.**"

```
curl -i -X POST \
 -d "url=https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" \
 -d "caption=test photo upload" \
 -d "access_token=<user_photos_user_access_token>" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/photos"
```

The EI connector documentation provides the following sample configuration [1]. We can observe that here the albumId is also passed with the postPhotoToAlbum operation. Since you are observing an invalid URL error response I suspect that you may have not configured these parameters correctly.

```
<facebook.postPhotoToAlbum>
        <albumId>{$url:album_id}</albumId>
        <apiUrl>https://graph.facebook.com</apiUrl>
        <apiVersion>{$url:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
        <accessToken>{$url:accessToken}</accessToken>
     </facebook.postPhotoToAlbum>
```

Even after configuring the albumid if you observe the same issue please enable wire logs in the EI server and check whether the correct request is passed to the Facebook API.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Facebook+Operations

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Response. I am able to understand what you are telling. And also from the curl command, I could see the "URL" value in -d (data option) option which represents which image I need to upload to Facebook. Is it possible to use local system filepath instead of using https URL.

Comment: @SaranyaK I have not tested this locally. But as per the sample request given in the documentation, it seems to be providing a local file.
 curl -X POST \-d "source=%7Bimage-data%7D" \ http://localhost:8280/services/facebook_postPhotoToAlbum/?album_id=1403293536601941